# move install directory for anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-server

I have anaconda installed on my ubuntu server in my home directory.  My user's home directory is on the same drive that my operating system is installed on.  I have another drive where I store most of my data, that's joined with a symbolic link to my home directory.  My anaconda installation takes up about 80GB, so I'd like to move it off the drive that my os is on.  There's a lot more room on the drive that I save my data to.  Is it possible to move the install directory for anaconda, and if I do is it likely to cause issues?

for example I'd like to move anaconda3 from /home/myuser/anaconda3 to /home/myuser_storage/anaconda3

where /home/myuser_storage is actually a symbolic link to another drive.